# Cannot convert method group 'FirstOrDefault' to non-delegate type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, lambda

I am retrieving a List and need to get a specific record.  I have tried doing it a couple of different ways, but each way produces an error.  I receive the aforementioned error using the following code:

```
List<DashboardModel> dashboardData = CompanyClient.GetContractorRankingByMajorIDAndContractorID(majorId, contractorId);
DashboardModel SSQScore = new DashboardModel();
SSQScore = dashboardData.Where(x=>x.ModuleInstanceID == 1).FirstOrDefault;
```

The List is returned by the method (GetContractor...).

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `FirstOrDefault();`. you forgot the parenthesis

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This

```
SSQScore = dashboardData.Where(x=>x.ModuleInstanceID == 1).FirstOrDefault;
```

should had been written like this

```
SSQScore = dashboardData.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.ModuleInstanceID == 1);
```

or you could just correct you statement, by using `()`, after `FirstOrDefault`,

```
SSQScore = dashboardData.Where(x=>x.ModuleInstanceID == 1).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> SSQScore = dashboardData.Where(x => x.ModuleInstanceID == 1).FirstOrDefault;
> ```

You miss the parentheses, which says to the compiler "use this method", instead of calling the method. Change it to

```
SSQScore = dashboardData.Where(x => x.ModuleInstanceID == 1).FirstOrDefault();
```

Alternatively, you do not need to do `Where(...).FirstOrDefault()`, the latter can take a predicate expression. This is equivalent:

```
SSQScore = dashboardData.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ModuleInstanceID == 1);
```

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary, possibly, I think we wrote it at the same time ;). It was too obvious :)

Comment: You two are great!  Thanks for the help.  I never would have figured out the missing ().